# Unable to communicate instructions for action resubmit that was already approved

Tags: facebook, submit, facebook-opengraph

My action was approved with Action Tagging. However after some time, I got a message that action tagging is not valid for my app and to consider using mention tagging. Currently the status is:

> Approval Status: Available to users (changes needed)  This Action Type
>   is available to all users, but your most recent submission needs
>   changes.
>
> Capabilities Status:
>
> - User Messages (Live) - Allow users to write a personalized message attached to this action.
> - Tags (Needs Change) - Allow users of my app   to tag other users for this action.
> - Explicitly Shared (Live) - This    action can specify the user explicitly shared an action.

So I implemented mention tagging, but each time I re-submit, I get the following response:

> We are unable to tell which additional properties you are requesting.
>   Please specify if you are planning to implement action tagging,
>   mention tagging, or both. If you are requesting mention tagging you
>   must select both the user message and tags action properties when
>   submitting your action. If you are requesting both action tagging and
>   mention tagging we will need to be able to reproduce both action
>   properties. For further information, please see here:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission_criteria/action_properties/#mentiontagging

Of course on resubmitting I explain very clearly that I want mention tagging and I show the steps to reproduce. I also have selected both the user message and tags action properties. It just seems that the testers simply ignore the message I write in the re-submit dialog.

I also puzzles me that the re-submit dialog has only the first step that you type in how to reproduce the action. It lacks the extra edit boxes that the normal submit dialog had the first time where you explained about the additional properties.

Maybe some kind of bug in the resubmit dialog of an already approved action (that needs changes in the additional properties) does not allow me to write the message I need?